# 404, 50x error handling HTML pages in nginx is not detected

Tags: nginx, http, http-status-code-404, 500-error

**nginx version: nginx/1.18.0**

This is my 'nginx' conf default 'vhost':

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/000-default
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    index index.html;

    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    root /home/www/example.org;

    include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    location / {
            # rewrite foobar.html to foobar, foobar.php to foobar
            if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    error_page   404  /404.html;

    location = /50x {
         root   /home/www/example.org;
         # rewrite foobar.html to foobar, foobar.php to foobar
         if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
         try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
    }
    location = /404 {
         root   /home/www/example.org;
         # rewrite foobar.html to foobar, foobar.php to foobar
         if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
         try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
    }
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.org.access.log;
}
```

I have both '404.html' and '50x.html' files in my root directory.

If I call them directly, It's a success, but if I try to get an unknown page like https://example.org/non-existant, I get `File not found` string instead of my HTML page.

Any help?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I need to do to make it works: there's was a conflict, I need to explicitly set known paths I want to rewrite index.html index.php to index (an so on):

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/000-default
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    index index.html;

    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    root /home/www/example.org;

    include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    location = /known {
            # rewrite foobar.html to foobar, foobar.php to foobar
            if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
    }
    location = /also-known {
            # rewrite foobar.html to foobar, foobar.php to foobar
            if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
    }
    location = /also-also-known {
            # rewrite foobar.html to foobar, foobar.php to foobar
            if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    error_page   404  /404.html;

    location = /50x {
         root   /home/www/example.org;
         internal;
    }
    location = /404 {
         root   /home/www/example.org;
         internal;
    }

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.org.access.log;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your configuration file, update the location block for the 404 and 50x error pages

just replace this block:

```
location = /50x {
    root   /home/www/example.org;
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
}
location = /404 {
    root   /home/www/example.org;
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
}
```

with

```
location = /50x.html {
    root /home/www/example.org;
    internal;
}
location = /404.html {
    root /home/www/example.org;
    internal;
}
```

then you can reload nginx `sudo nginx -s reload` it should work properly.

Comment: Sorry, thanks, but same behavior. Just get `File not found.`

Comment: See my answer, you helped me++, but not the main issue. Thanks anyway